# Iterate through string return index `replaceAt` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, character

I'm running a code similar to the following in a browser:

```
let str = "hello.\n"
console.log(srt);
for (let i in str) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(str [i]);
}
```

I can't figure out why the loop does not stop at the last character? Here is the output:

```
Hello.

core.js:57 0
core.js:58 H
core.js:57 1
core.js:58 e
core.js:57 2
core.js:58 l
core.js:57 3
core.js:58 l
core.js:57 4
core.js:58 o
core.js:57 5
core.js:58 .
core.js:57 6
core.js:58 

core.js:57 replaceAt
core.js:58 ƒ (index,newChar){return this.substr(0,index)+newChar+this.substr(index+newChar.length);}
```

I try to reproduce the problem, but it works fine outside my whole application. Of course, the problem comes from my app, but I don't even understand why the loop does not stop at index 6 (last character).

I don't either understand what is the last printed index `replaceAt`, any idea?

The string length is 7 character as expected.

```
// Display 7 in the console
console.log (str.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something in your application is polluting your `String` prototype along the lines of the following:

```js
String.prototype.replaceAt = function (index,newChar){return this.substr(0,index)+newChar+this.substr(index+newChar.length);};

let str = "hello.\n"
console.log(str);
for (let i in str) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(str [i]);
}
```

Comment: The string comes from a JS array `let test = [
    { 
        image: "/dev/images/img0.svg",
        text: "this is a zero."
    },...` and I removed all the operations on the string. The string only travels through functions parameters.

Comment: I'm not talking about this specific string. I'm talking about the string *prototype*.